# Will somebody look over my real-analysis/calculus solution of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sqrt{9+t^2}\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, proof-verification, derivatives

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sqrt{9+t^2}\mathrm{d}t$.

Immediately, taking,

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sqrt{9+t^2}\mathrm{d}t \\
=&\frac{\lim_{x\to 0} \int_0^{x} \sqrt{9+t^2}\mathrm{d}t}{ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align}$$
which yields the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. 
Recall the

> ***Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (1)***:   If $f$ is *Riemann integrable* on $[a,b]$ for $a\leq x\leq b$, put $F(x)=\int_0^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$. Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$: furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and $F'(x)=f(x)$.

From this point, using *L'Hospital's Rule* yields
$$\begin{align} 
&\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x}\sqrt{9+x^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
\rightarrow& 1 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}F'(x)\\
\rightarrow& \lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{9+x^2}\\
=& 3.
\end{align}$$\
I feel like I have assumed something that I shouldn't have. Could somebody look this over for me?

Comment: Your solution is fine, your notation is strange.

Comment: Your basic method is fine, if we imagine the function $\int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}\,dt$ to be also defined for some negative $x$. There are "better" (less manipulational) ways.

Comment: This can be done readily without L'Hopital's rule.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct but you do not need to use L'Hospital's rule.
Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^x \sqrt{t^2+9}dt$.
 Then you have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=F^\prime(0)$$

by definition of the derivative and the FTC gives you that $F^\prime(t)=\sqrt{t^2+9}$.

Comment: How do i deal with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ without using L'Hospital?

Edit: Nevermind, I see exactly what you are saying. Thanks for thie tip

Comment: @Kyle H. you do not need to deal with it. What is the **definition** the derivative of the function at zero?

Comment: Just to be clear though, it's because $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \sqrt{9+t^2}dt\right) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_0^{x}\sqrt{9+t^2}dt}{x}$ right?

Comment: The idea you note is central to proving certain forms of L'Hopital's rule, so in a sense they are equivalent.

Comment: @Kyle H. Sure, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the solution per se, but there are some errors in the presentation. When you invoke L'Hospital's rule, you write $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}$ when you mean $\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx} x},$ and also note that $F'(x) = \sqrt{9 + x^2}$, not $\sqrt{9+t^2}$, but other than that it's just fine!

Comment: Thanks for the keen eye, I have fixed it.